# How to make dua? Please help!

Tags: salat, dua

I am very confused because I'm not sure at what point in my prayer that i'm suppose to do dua.

Do I do dua in a fard prayer? Do I do dua between the tashahhud and salam? Do I do dua after salam (end of prayer)? Do I do dua in sujood? And how do you do dua in sujood? Is it after saying subhaana rubbi alalla? And at which rakkah do you say it?

What is the sequence of dua?(praise Allah and the prophet, dua for the muslims, dua for the country, dua for the family and friends, and then dua for myself) Is that in the right order? or there is no order?

When I mean dua, I mean when we ask Allah for things and forgiveness and for family and friends,...etc.

I'm sorry if there are lots of questions. I just need clarification especially since the last 10 days of Ramadan I need to make dua.

Thank you very much.

Comment: check this out: https://islamqa.info/en/answers/7886/the-proper-way-to-make-duaa-during-prayer

Comment: @ThaierAlkhateeb Thank you, that link is a big help. I just have a question: In the sujood, should I make dua before or after saying subhaana rubbi alalla three times? And is it in the last rakka?

Comment: These are a whole bunch of questions which should be asked separately. Note that some of them might already be covered on the site. Also be aware that many parts of the prayer are or includes  a kind of dhikr (du'a).